# Migration from oracle to DB2

Tags: oracle, migration, db2

I want to migrate my oracle schema to db2.
Any tool available for migration?
Please help

Comment: Since both ends are commercial software, shouldn't you talk to the people you are paying for support first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM have a free tool called the [IBM Data Movement Tool](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0906datamovement/) that can assist with this.

They have also published a very useful Redbook that can probably answer all of your questions and more.  It's called: [Oracle to DB2 Conversion Guide: Compatibility Made Easy](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247736.html)

Comment: Check all the forums, articles and blogs about DB2 enablement: db2night show, "SQL tips for DB2 LUW" blog, developerWorks forums, wikis and artcles.

Answer (score 2):

I think Oracle's recently-acquired 'GoldenGate' product will allow you to do that.